# How to send two JSON values from view to controller using EF

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, controller

This is my script:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};



function btnadHocSave() {
    debugger
    var lv_header = $("#Header").serializeObject(); // this is header <fieldset> tag
    var lv_detail = $("#SubmitMachine").serializeObject(); // this is detail <fieldset> tag
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateMachine")',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            myheader: lv_header,
            mydetail: lv_detail
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success!..");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    })
}
```

This is my action code. `PMAllotmentEntry` and `PMAllotmentDetailEntry` are models:

```
public ActionResult UpdateMachine(PMAllotmentEntry myheader, PMAllotmentDetailEntry mydetail)
{
    return View();
}
```

Now my problem I'm not able get the values from view to controller.
I tried `JSON.stringify` also but there is no use.

It is working If I pass single JSON value.

I tried out all the possibilities. Did as you said also but no use. Finally I did the following. I got two JSON values but still facing a issues because JSON second values first field value coming with first JSON values.

```
       function btnadHocSave() {
            debugger

            var lv_header = $("#Header").serialize(); // this is header <fieldset>
            var lv_detail = $("#SubmitMachine").serialize();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/PMAllotments/UpdateMachine',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: lv_header + ',' + lv_detail,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Success!..");
                        debugger
                        $("#adHocAdd40").modal("hide");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                })
        }
```

Comment: For a start you need to use `data: JSON.stringify({ myheader: lv_header, mydetail: lv_detail}),` but why are you using that `serializeObject()` function (which will fail as soon as you have a `bool` property) and the fact your sending the data like that suggests your not generating your view correctly

Comment: The Best way to do this is create a New class and put those "PMAllotmentEntry myheader, PMAllotmentDetailEntry mydetail" classes in to one class .

Comment: Regarding you edit - remove the `contentType` option and its `data: lv_header + '&' + lv_detail,` (but that assumes your view is generated correctly - but you have not shown any of that -, and the fact your writing this code suggests you have not)

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm removed JQuery from cshtml file and simply used post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateMachine(PMAllotmentEntry m)
{
    //complete the task
    return View();
}
```

**replaced foreach loop in .cshtml file with for loop**

FOR loop is highly important foreach loop never return your child model data.

```
@for (int a = 0; a < Model.PMAllotmentDetail.Count; a++)
{
     @* table rows here *@
}
```

My Model as following

```
[NotMapped]
public class PMAllotmentEntry
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 PMAllotmentId { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessage ="Add atleast one machine!")]
    public List<PMAllotmentDetailEntry> PMAllotmentDetail { get; set; }


}

[NotMapped]
public class PMAllotmentDetailEntry
{

    [Key]
    public Int64 PMAllotmentDetailId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PMAllotmentId")]
    public Int64 PMAllotmentId { get; set; }

}
```